# How to change date picker formcontrol value format with moment in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs

I followed the example on [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) for how to use moment with the material date picker and change the default format by providing MAT_DATE_FORMATS. The example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ymjrpvgymjr). Note: the code doesn't work correctly in stackblitz, it seems to be ignoring the provided date formats but it does work correctly in my environment.

My issue is when I access the form control's value and convert it to JSON it always outputs "2018-01-16T15:44:33.897Z". I need it to output the date only "2018-01-16". Also I would prefer the date picker not add a time attribute at all. How can I make this work the way I want?

I know you can call moment's `format` function and get the date formatted any way you want but my form has many fields and I would prefer to just send `form.value` to my api. If I wanted to use moment's `format` function I would have to iterating over each control, check its type, get the value and format it individually, collect all the values into an object and then send it to my api which is a lot of extra coding just so I can format date controls.

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396025/how-to-customize-date-in-mat-datepicker-to-2017-11-20t112300-angular-mater?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up extending the moment object and overriding the toJSON method. I also copied and edited the MomementDateAdapter so it also used the edited version of moment and also created everything in UTC.

This is the moment override:

```
// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';
export class MomentConstructor
{
    static getInstance() {
        const original = _rollupMoment || _moment;
        original.prototype.toJSON = function() {
            return this.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        }
        return original;
    }
}

//export the typing for Moment so it is easier to import into other classes
export interface Moment extends _moment.Moment {}
```

For the moment date adapter I found and copied the one provided by Material and edited it so that the moment import looked like this:

```
import { MomentConstructor, Moment } from './moment-date-only';
const moment = MomentConstructor.getInstance();
```

and I did a find replace on " moment(" and replaced it with " moment.utc(".

I built out an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-date-moment-utc) but like I said in my question, stackblitz doesn't handle the adapter right so in order to see it working properly you need to implement it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a Moment date, maybe you could use it ? Simply convert it before doign what are about to do. Something along the lines of (I don't Moment a lot, but this gives you an idea) :

```
const myStringDate = moment(this.myDatePickerValue; 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

[**Look at the documentation**](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to find what suits you !

Comment: I would much prefer having the form handle the formatting itself

Comment: In this case you will have to make a custom directive for that, that updates the input value on every change

Comment: I am using material date picker with the moment adapter and formcontrols. The date picker uses the form control with the moment set as the value. It handles changing the display value and formatting it correctly to a long date format. I cant change the value of the control or it will affect this functionality (as I understand it).

Answer (score 0):

You can change date value format with moment in angular using pipe, first you need to install momentjs, implement your transform pipe function.

```
import {Pipe, ChangeDetectorRef, PipeTransform, OnDestroy, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

// under systemjs, moment is actually exported as the default export, so we account for that
const momentConstructor: (value?: any) => moment.Moment = (<any>moment).default || moment;

@Pipe({name: 'amTimeAgo', pure: false})
export class TimeAgoPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
  private currentTimer: number;

  private lastTime: Number;
  private lastValue: Date | moment.Moment;
  private lastOmitSuffix: boolean;
  private lastText: string;

  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private ngZone: NgZone) {
  }

  transform(value: Date | moment.Moment, omitSuffix?: boolean): string {
    if (this.hasChanged(value, omitSuffix)) {
      this.lastTime = this.getTime(value);
      this.lastValue = value;
      this.lastOmitSuffix = omitSuffix;
      this.removeTimer();
      this.createTimer();
      this.lastText = momentConstructor(value).from(momentConstructor(), omitSuffix);

    } else {
      this.createTimer();
    }

    return this.lastText;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.removeTimer();
  }


  private createTimer() {
    if (this.currentTimer) {
      return;
    }
    const momentInstance = momentConstructor(this.lastValue);

    const timeToUpdate = this.getSecondsUntilUpdate(momentInstance) * 1000;
    this.currentTimer = this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        return window.setTimeout(() => {
          this.lastText = momentConstructor(this.lastValue).from(momentConstructor(), this.lastOmitSuffix);

          this.currentTimer = null;
          this.ngZone.run(() => this.cdRef.markForCheck());
        }, timeToUpdate);
      }
    });
  }


  private removeTimer() {
    if (this.currentTimer) {
      window.clearTimeout(this.currentTimer);
      this.currentTimer = null;
    }
  }

  private getSecondsUntilUpdate(momentInstance: moment.Moment) {
    const howOld = Math.abs(momentConstructor().diff(momentInstance, 'minute'));
    if (howOld < 1) {
      return 1;
    } else if (howOld < 60) {
      return 30;
    } else if (howOld < 180) {
      return 300;
    } else {
      return 3600;
    }
  }

  private hasChanged(value: Date | moment.Moment, omitSuffix?: boolean) {
    return this.getTime(value) !== this.lastTime || omitSuffix !== this.lastOmitSuffix;
  }

  private getTime(value: Date | moment.Moment) {
    if (moment.isDate(value)) {
      return value.getTime();
    } else if (moment.isMoment(value)) {
      return value.valueOf();
    } else {
      return momentConstructor(value).valueOf();
    }
  }
}
```